# As a developer, how can I troubleshoot JavaScript issues in Amazon's Silk browser?

Tags: kindle-fire

I noticed a bug in my web app that **only** appears in the Amazon Silk browser, on a Kindle Fire HD 6. As you might imagine, debugging it on a 6" screen with no keyboard sounds like torture.

I've debugged similar problems in Mobile Safari using desktop Safari's [Web Inspector](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787) with an iPhone or iPad plugged in to my laptop over USB.

Is there any similar capability for Silk?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you install the Android Debug Bridge and follow these directions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/remote-debugging.html